# non writing replace/update in rethinkdb query

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I'm new to rethinkdb and have simple trouble.
Suppose I have following objects structure:

```
Table A:
[{
    'id': '1',
    'b_list': ['11', '12']
}]
Table B:
[{
    'id': '11',
    'value': 'somevalue1'
},{
    'id': '12',
    'value': 'somevalue2'
}]
```

So instance of "A" keeps relations to two "B" instances.

What query should I do in rethinkdb to retrieve following response?

```
[{
    'id': '1',
    'b_list': [
        {
            'id': '11',
            'value': 'somevalue1'
        },{
            'id': '12',
            'value': 'somevalue2'
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to see instances of B instead of their ids in response and I don't want this change to be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with an `eq_join` like so:

```
r.table("A")
  .map(lambda x: 
    x.merge({
      "b_list" :
        x["b_list"].eq_join(lambda x: x, r.table("B"))["right"]})
```

For a single document:

```
r.table("A").get(pk)
  .do(lambda x: 
    x.merge({
      "b_list" :
        x["b_list"].eq_join(lambda x: x, r.table("B"))["right"]})
```

Comment: yeah, you are right, that's it.
that works fine if I need to fetch all data from table A this way.
but what if I need this only for one record, with id = "1"
there is no need to use map anymore but we still need merge
r.table("A").get("1").merge({'b_list': XXX["b_list"].eq_join(lambda bla bla bla)})
what should I put instead of XXX there to access doc I'm currently merging. is there something like 'self' in queries?

Comment: If it's only one document then you want to use `do` instead of `map`, I'm going to edit the answer to include it.